# derived classes in maps

Tags: c++

i have two independent class hierarchies, starting at `BaseClass1`, `BaseClass2`

this is what I want to do:

```
struct BaseClass1 {
  virtual void obtain_map(std::map<int,BaseClass2> &map) = 0;
}
```

Subclasses of `BaseClass1` override the `obtain_map`. But the problem is that those sublcasses should be able to use subclasses of `BaseClass2` in the `map` parameter. (So in this sense, subclasses of the two "independent" hierarchies are actually related, or rather can be if the subclass designers want)

How can I accomplish this, or am I forced to create my own `map` class from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you derive your classes like so and use pointer as the second `map` template parameter (a smart pointer like `std::unique_ptr` will save you some memory management trouble):

```
struct BaseClass1 {
    virtual void obtain_map(std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<BaseClass2>> &map) = 0;
};
struct DerivedClass1 : public BaseClass1 {
    virtual void obtain_map(std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<BaseClass2>> &map) override
    {
    }
};
```

You can still pass in `maps` with derived versions of BaseClass2 as the second type:

```
struct DerivedClass2 : public BaseClass2;
// ...

std::map<int, std::unique<DerivedClass2>> mdc2;
DerivedClass1 dc1;
dc1.obtain_map(mdc2);
```

Comment: But who's responsibility would it be to free the pointer? This is the problem with this random "hacks" isn't it... :( or is this some known design pattern in the c++ world?

Comment: @user2015453 This isn't a random hack.  `std::unique_ptr` manages the memory deallocation itself when it goes out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

STL containers only store fixed size objects. If yo push BaseClass2 derived class object to `std::map<int,BaseClass2>`, objects will be sliced to BaseClass2 type.

If you want `std::map` to store subclasses of BaseClass2, you need to store pointer(smart pointer) in map.

For example:

```
  struct BaseClass1 {
    virtual void obtain_map(std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<BaseClass2>> &map) = 0;
  }

   struct DerivedClass1 : public BaseClass1 {
   virtual void obtain_map(std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<BaseClass2>> &map)
   {
      // implementation
   }
 }
```

Storing smpart pointers has the advances compare to raw poiter because you don't need to  manually delete memories the pointers are pointing to.